# Kubernetes Ingress not working when trying to expose kubernetes-dashboard with it

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, dashboard, minikube, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to expose kubernetes-dashboard through nginx-ingress. The kubernetes-dashboard was not available already but I had initialized all the resources using the following .yaml file shared on the kubernetes [official file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.6.1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml).

All the resources were provisioned accordingly. Here is the output of the following command I ran to check `kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard`

Output:

```bash
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-8c47d4b5d-7dptt   1/1     Running   1 (78m ago)   9h
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-6c75475678-4c9n2       1/1     Running   0             9h

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.105.70.143    <none>        8000/TCP        14h
service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.111.136.242   <none>        443:32361/TCP   14h

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           9h
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           9h

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-8c47d4b5d   1         1         1       9h
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-6c75475678       1         1         1       9h
```

I also changed the service type for the **service/kubernetes-dashboard** to NodePort from ClusterIP as shown above in the output.

The following is the yaml file I used to create my ingress resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.ml
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

I can't seem to access the kubernetes-dashboard still. The host in the above yaml is not a legit hostname but I added the following resolution of hostname in my **/etc/hosts** files as `192.168.49.2    test.ml`

The following is the detail about my ingress after running command `kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard`

Output:

```bash
NAME                CLASS    HOSTS     ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   <none>   test.ml   192.168.49.2   80      14h
```

Whenever I try to access the IP address or through the hostname I still can't access my kubernetes-dashboard. I'm using minikube running on my localhost with the VM driver podman and container-runtime is docker.

Comment: Did you follow any guides like [this one](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_Kubernetes_Nginx_Ingress_Controller_for_Dashboard_on_Minikube.php)?

Comment: I was following an old tutorial i belive. But i will surely have a look into what you have shared and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please choose a [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) and create NodePort for the service to access dashboard application.  Below are [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites) details.

Prerequisites
You must have an Ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect.

You may need to deploy an Ingress controller such as ingress-nginx. You can choose from a number of Ingress controllers.

Ideally, all Ingress controllers should fit the reference specification. In reality, the various Ingress controllers operate slightly differently.